# Redirect with Ajax / JQuery / PhoneGab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, phonegap-build

I use PhoneGab for *my firstime*, and something wrong...

I woodlike use the **window.location.href** method when I receive 'data' (**json** response from **PHP** before an **Ajax** request(cross domain)).

But when I test this think on my mobile(Android), the redirection doesn't work...

ps: everything is usually fine on web browser.

Does anyone see the problem?

That's my code :

```
<html> <head>
    <title>Ajax Cross-Origin</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> </head>

<body>

<div id="body-inside" data-role="page">
        <div class="logo-inside">
            <a href="index.html" class="connexionForm">
                  <span id="arrowLeft" class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="titre"><h1 id="inscTitle">Inscription</h1></div>
        <form class="FormInscription" method="POST">
            <label>Nom</label>
            <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" placeholder="nom"/>
            <label>Prénom</label>
            <input type="text" name="prenom" id="prenom" placeholder="prénom"/>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="xyz@email.com"/>
            <label>Mot de passe</label>
            <input type="password" name="password1" id="mdp1" placeholder="xxx123"/>
            <label>Confirmer votre mot de passe :</label>
            <input type="password" name="password2" id="mdp2" placeholder="xxx123"/>
            <button id="saveLogin" >
                Suivant
             </button>
        </form>
      </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function redirect(){
            window.location.href = "inscription_suite.html";
        } $(function() {    
    $( '#saveLogin' ).click(function(){
                var nom     = $("#nom").val();
                var prenom  = $("#prenom").val();
                var email   = $("#email").val();
                var mdp1    = $("#mdp1").val();
                var mdp2    = $("#mdp2").val();


        $.post( "http://webawards.io/data.php",{ 
                    firstname   : nom,   
                    lastname    : prenom,
                    mail        : email, 
                    pass1       : mdp1,  
                    pass2       : mdp2

                },function( data ) {
                    if(data!=="false"){
                        sessionStorage.setItem("id", data);
                        redirect();
                    } else if(data=="false"){
                        alert("Une erreur semble s'être produite, veuillez réessayer");
                    }
                });
    });
     });  </script>

</body> </html>
```

Comment: Are you aware that both [Google and Apple frown on apps](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005a) that are website wrappers? In addition, best practice is to have the webpage on the device.

Comment: Jesse is right. That's why Google and Apple added the "Add to Homescreen" options, where a user can add your webpage right to their homescreen.

Answer (score 0):

The updated cordova version doesn't allow you to redirect via javascript. You need to follow the instructions in order to make the javascript redirect work.

Add the "[Cordova Whitelist Plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist)" in your config.xml

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.1.0" />
```

Or simply

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.1.0" />
```

Try putting the following in your config.xml

```
<content src="index.html" />
```

is the path to your HTML file inside the source directory.

```
<access origin="*" />
```

will allow you to redirect to any of the external page using JS. If you want to restrict your app to just a single domain then use it like this.

```
<access origin="http://yourdomain.com" />
```

At the end, put the following intents

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```